# Maximizing $3 x^2+2 \sqrt{2} x y$ with $x^4+y^4=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I want to have maxizing value of $3 x^2+2 \sqrt{2} x y$  when $x^4+y^4=1$, $x>0,y>0$.
How can I solve it.

Comment: @Théophile I had try a arithmetic geometric mean inequality, and inequality of de Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: That's a good start. It would be helpful to explain this in your question to show that you've put some thought into it. Have you tried Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: @Théophile But I want a method of precalculus. and the solution is $2  √5$ by using Mathematica.

Comment: you can solve $$x^4+y^4=1$$ for $$y$$ or $$x$$ and you have got a problem in one variable

Answer (score 4):

I have got solution with precaculus method. thank you everyone advices.

$3 x^2+2 \sqrt{2} x y$

$\leq$ $3 x^2+\left(x^2+2 y^2\right)$

$=$ $4 x^2+2 y^2$    (when equal is  $x=\sqrt{2} y$ with arithmetic geometric mean inequality )

$=$ $2\cdot \left(2 x^2\right)+1\cdot \left(2
   y^2\right)$

$\leq$ $\sqrt{\left(2^2+1^2\right) \left(\left(2
   x^2\right)^2+\left(2
   y^2\right)^2\right)}$

$=$ $\sqrt{\left(2^2+1^2\right) \left(4 x^4+4
   y^4\right)}$     (when equal is  $x=\sqrt{2} y$ with inequality of de Cauchy-Schwarz)

$=$ $\sqrt{5\cdot 4}$

$=$ $2 \sqrt{5}$

And I also can got the the solution with comment of @Théophile .

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: nice use of cauchy-schwartz. +1

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do this: let us parametrize the constraint $$x^4 + y^4 = 1, x > 0, y > 0 \text{ by } x = \sqrt{\cos t}, y = \sqrt{\sin t}, 0 < t < \pi/2.$$  we need to maximise $$ f = 3x^2 + 2\sqrt 2xy=3\cos t + 2\sqrt 2\sqrt{\cos t \sin t} = 3\cos t + 2\sqrt{\sin 2t}, 0 < t < \pi/2$$
taking the derivative of $f$ and seeting it to zero, you have $$f' = -3\sin t + 2\frac{\cos 2t}{\sqrt{\sin 2t}}$$

only critical number of $f$ is $t = 0.4636$ and this is a global max $4.4721$ for $f(t),\,  0 \le t \le \pi/2.$

Comment: Where $0.4636\ldots = \sin^{-1}{\sqrt 5 \over 5}$ and $4.4721\ldots = 2\sqrt5$.

Comment: @Théophile,  thanks. i got the critical number by solving $f'(t) = 0$ numerically. is there a way to do this analytically? i will be interested to know.

Comment: I'm curious too! The solution is $x = \left(\frac45\right)^\frac14, y = \left(\frac15\right)^\frac14$, but I'm not sure how to get it.

Comment: Using $\sin t=\sqrt{(1-\cos 2t)/2}$ one can rewrite $f'(t)=0$ as a 4th degree equation for $\cos 2t$, whose only acceptable solution is $3/5$.